# Properly power down SSD during shutdown

Tags: debian, usb, shutdown, smart

I recently got a Samsung SSD.  I have debian wheezy installed on it. I carry it around in a USB enclosure and boot both my work and home computers from it.   How can I ensure that the system properly powers down the drive during shutdown?  The following SMART metrics seem to indicate that it doesn't:

```
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME     FLAG    VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE     UPDATED WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
 12 Power_Cycle_Count  0x0032  099   099   000    Old_age  Always      -       24
235 Unknown_Attribute  0x0012  099   099   000    Old_age  Always      -       23
```

I believe the numbers indicate the drive has been powered up 24 times and has lost power unexpectedly 23 times, i.e. every power down.  The metrics are described on [Samsung's website](http://www.samsung.com/global/business/semiconductor/minisite/SSD/global/html/about/whitepaper07.html) as follows:

> ID # 12 Power-On Count
>
> The raw value of this attribute reports the cumulative number of power on/off cycles. This includes both sudden power off and normal power off cases.
>
> ID # 235 Power Recovery Count
>
> A count of the number of sudden power off cases. If there is a sudden power off, the firmware must recover all of the mapping and user data during the next power on. This is a count of the number of times this has happened.

I read that unexpected power loss is bad for an SSD.

**Edit:** Now I'm not sure this is a real question.  I tried attaching the drive to a different system, putting it to sleep with `hdparm -Y /dev/sdX`, and then disconnecting the USB cable.  It still increments the power recovery count.  I tried this with three different enclosures.  I think I'll take this issue to Samsung.

Comment: Hmmm, maybe a driver issue.  I have a crucial m4 with a count of 2000 for ID 12, no listing for 235 but (different manufacturer of course) 0 for 174, "Unexpect_Power_Loss_Ct".